# "InvalidDataException: Form value count limit 1024 exceeded." model null when post more then 1000 values from view to controller in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, bootstrap-multiselect

I'm trying to sent bulk email to selected candidates based on roles. When I'm selected limited options then model pass properly, but once I select more then 1000 option from `multiselect` dropdown and post from the model passed null.

Very Strang, Is there any reason for that?

**Email Template View model**

```
public class EmailTemplateViewModel
{
    public EmailTemplateViewModel()
    {
        LstEmailTemplate = new List<EmailTemplateModel>();
        
        SendEmailModel = new SendEmailModel();
    }
    public List<EmailTemplateModel> LstEmailTemplate { get; set; }
   
    public Pager Pager { get; set; }
    public SendEmailModel SendEmailModel { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
    @model Practise.Models.EmailTemplateViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("SentBulkEMail", "EmailTemplate", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
                {
                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.SendEmailModel.EmailTemplateId, new { id = "hdnEmailTemplateId" })
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">User Type</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SendEmailModel.Roles, new SelectList(Roles, "Value", "Text"), new { id = "Roles", @class = "form-control select2", multiple = "multiple", @required = "required" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Recipients</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SendEmailModel.Recipient, new SelectList(ViewBag.Recipient as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>), "", new { id = "Recipients", multiple = "multiple", @required = "required", @class = "form-control" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Subject</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.SendEmailModel.Subject, new { id = "subject", @class = "form-control", @required = "required" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Message</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                            @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.SendEmailModel.Description, new { id = "hdndescription", @class = "form-control", @required = "required" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Send</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> SentBulkEMail(EmailTemplateViewModel emailTemplateViewModel)
        {
            CustomResponseModel response = new CustomResponseModel();
            response = await _emailTemplateService.SentBulkEmail(Request);
            if (response.IsSuccess)
            {
                TempData[Constant.Success] = response.Message;
            }
            else
            {
                TempData[Constant.Error] = response.Message;
            }
            return RedirectToAction("List");
        }
```

You can get better idea from below image:

**1st I select only 4 option from multi select**
[image]

**Controller when select 4 options**
[image]

**2nd  select more then 1000**

[image]

**Controller when I select more than 1000 options**
[image]

Comment: Have you checked the browser's network tab to confirm whether the POST call actually contains a json payload (and its format matches EmailTemplateViewModel?)

Comment: @RJ i'm just posting a form does it matter for json payload?

Comment: Values in form is converted to JSON model when posted to server and at the server that JSON is deserialized back to object which is available in POST action. So if you look at the network trace using browser developer tools or Fiddler, you can check what is being passed to the server from the view.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally I found an answer.

The default request value is limited up to **`1024`** .

For that we need to set the request limit using **RequestFormLimits** attribute like follows:

```
[HttpPost]
[RequestFormLimits(ValueCountLimit = Int32.MaxValue)]
public async Task<IActionResult> SentBulkEMail(SendEmailModel emailModel)
{
}
```

After adding this attribute with **ValueCountLimit** allow request value up to `Int32.MaxValue` or you can set as per your requirement.